# Compilation Errors on .at(i) but not on [i]

Tags: syntax-error, at-command, c-strings

Why is it that:

`char SourceChar = Text.c_str()[Index];`
compiles, but

`char SourceChar = Text.c_str().at(Index);`
does not?  Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: @terminus Consistency, mostly.

Comment: Then why not use std::string::at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text.c_str() returns a 'const char *' which is a C type, so it's not an object. You can only access it's value with Text[i] or *(Text + i).

If you want to access the i-th character in a more OOP manner you could use Text[i] or Text.at(i).